# longtabu is not working in combination with \usepackage{floatrow}

Tags: floatrow, longtabu

Latex newbie here. I currently trying to write my thesis and wanne include a pretty long table. Had several issues already regarding this table but now I think using the usepackage {longtabu} might help. However, I'm using the usepackage{flowrow} and just discovered that those guys don't like each other (or maybe I'm just stupid). Here is an example to make my point clear (mostlly stolen from another issue):

```
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage{floatrow}


\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {
    X[1,c]
    X[1,c]
    X[1,c]
    X[10,l]}
    \hline \hline
    \textbf{Time End of Step} & 
    \textbf{Step} & 
    \textbf{Event} &
    \textbf{Description} 
    \\ \hline \hline \hline \hline
    12:18:52 & 1 & 1 & this is a description for the event \\
    12:18:52 & 1 & 1 & this is a description for the event \\
    12:18:52 & 1 & 1 & this is a description for the event \\
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

This one works totally fine and is creating a table. However, when uncommenting the %\usepackage{floatrow} the error: "! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup." appears.
Is there anything I can do to use both packages at the same time? Am I doing anything wrong? Or is it somehow possible to "deactivate" floatrow just before using longtabu and reactivate it afterward again? I appreciate any help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: read the readme here and then consider if your really want to use tabu. https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/

Comment: For long tables with `X` columns, you might be interested by the `xltabular` package, and its eponymous environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of `xltabular`, `booktabs` (horizontal lines) and `makecell`(column headers):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{cccX}
    \toprule
    \thead{Time End\\ of Step} & 
    \thead{Step} & 
    \thead{Event} &
    \thead{Description} 
    \\ \midrule
    12:18:52 & 1 & 1 & this is a description for the event \\
    12:18:52 & 1 & 1 & this is a description for the event \\
    12:18:52 & 1 & 1 & this is a description for the event \\
\end{xltabular}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{cccX}
    \toprule
    \thead{Time End of Step} & 
    \thead{Step} & 
    \thead{Event} &
    \thead{Description} 
    \\ \midrule
    12:18:52 & 1 & 1 & this is a description for the event \\
    12:18:52 & 1 & 1 & this is a description for the event \\
    12:18:52 & 1 & 1 & this is a description for the event \\
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```